How is a steady current maintained in case of motional EMF if net force on electrons is zero?
I looked at the derivation of emf induced in case of a conducting rod entering a uniform magnetic field perpendicular to it, emf$=Bvl$ if $B$ is the strength of magnetic field,  $v$ and $l$ are velocity of the rod and length of the rod respectively. In it we at the step where we equate the force due to the electric field in the rod to the Lorentz force on the electrons moving along with the rod perpendicular to the magnetic field.
V=El
E=V/l
V/l * q= qvB(magnitudes)
V=Blv
So if there is no net force on the electrons and if they are slowed down or are sent in random directions once they encounter resistance in the wire then how should a steady current keep flowing?
As in case of a current being driven by a battery the electric field accelerates the electrons which subsequently loose the energy in collisions with the lattice and again get accelerated by the electric field. In this case net force = 0 so net acceleration must be 0 hence I'm not able to see a way to provide the electrons Kinetic energy back again which got lost due to resistance.
Please tell me where I'm going wrong here.


if they are slowed down or are sent in random directions once they encounter resistance in the wire then how should a steady current keep flowing?

If the rod is isolated, only then electric charge rearranges on its surface in such a way so that net motive force on mobile charges inside is zero. There is no current in the rod then, and the rod keeps in uniform motion, without being slowed down by the magnetic force $BIL$.
If the rod rolls on rails which are conductively connected on the other end, so that the rod is part of a conductive closed path, then electric charge can't rearrange on the rod surface to make net motive force inside zero. Instead, the motional EMF keeps pushing mobile charge inside the rod along, and into the rails. Thus, we have a current in the "circuit", and the rod is slowed down by the magnetic force $BIL$.

Indeed there is no current in the rod once the force on the electrons become zero.
While the rod was entering in the magnetic field , the magnetic force acted on the free electrons to produce a current for some time in the rod until the potential became enough to stop that.
After that if you keep moving that rod at the same velocity $v$ and connect a wire (of resistance $R$) with the two ends of the rod , then the rod would act as a battery due to its emf ($vBl$).Then only current would start flowing in the rod again.
If there is no external connection and the rod is still moving with same conditions , then it would be like a charged battery and no current flows inside a battery on its own until it is connected to a wire to draw some electrons into it ( that is the same case ).

So in the case when it is connected to another wire of resistance R , then would it be possible for the rod to have some internal resistance? As met force in steady state on electrons in rod again becomes zero then it can't have an internal resistance right?

@ArushDesai  It can have an internal resistance and having net force on electrons to be zero doesn't ensure anything about resistance.

What I feel is if Lorentz force ( driver) and force due to electric field inside due to potential difference are same then there won't be a way to again accelerate the electrons once being retarded by resistance, is something wrong with the reasoning? And as a consequence we will have to have Lorentz force greater than force due to electric field across resistance and net gain in energy hence is again lost as heat.

@ArushDesai In steady state , i.e. when there is steady current in the wire - rod (battery) circuit , the rod would draw electrons from the wire into itself which would disturb the voltage and hence there would be some force on the electrons which would try to make that same EMF in the rod and so even in steady state the net force on the electrons is not zero.

Ookayy, so it's the instantaneous charge separation and subsequent decrease in it due to constant supple of electrons from a closed circuit.  Thank you very much for answering
